# Where is the file that store the path to the android sdk?

Tags: android, eclipse

Where is the file that store the path to the android sdk? I want to change the sdk location directly via the file but not via the eclipse preference.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add the platform-tools\ directory to your Windows path:  ;C:\Development\Android\android-sdk-windows\platform-tools\

NOTE: The last "\" at the end of the Path variable has to be included.

MAC: Update the PATH variable to point to the Android SDK Platform-tools directory in the /etc/rc.common file or ~/.bash_profile:

PATH=/bin:/sbin:/usr/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/libexec:/System/Library/CoreServices:/Developer/usr/bin:~/Development/Android/android-sdk-macosx/tools:~/Development/Android/android-sdk-macosx/platform-tools:export PATH

LINUX: Update your PATH to point to the Android SDK Platform-tools directory. If you use bash shell, add the following to ~/.bashrc :

export PATH=/opt/android-sdk-linux/tools/:/opt/android-sdk-linux/platform-tools/:$PATH

The Eclipse environment is now ready for Android development.